# Reading survey data CSV with multiple selection sub-columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to import this data from a Navigraph survey results.
https://navigraph.com/blog/survey2022

The dataset is here:
https://download.navigraph.com/docs/flightsim-community-survey-by-navigraph-2022-data.zip

However, I noticed the structure is something I'm not quite used to, and perhaps this is how a lot of polling data is shared. The semicolons being separators is not an issue. It's the fact there's a mix of "select multiple" responses as columns. The tidiest thing is starting at the third row, each row is a single respondent.

How can I clean up this data so it is as "tidy" as possible? How would I `melt()` these columns into rows? How do I handle the multiple selection responses in the sub-columns?

I'd like the questions and responses to simply be two columns respectively.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Hello how are you? I don't have full knowledge in this type of work but I believe you will have to:

1- Read the file as is
2- Concatenate the columns of questions and answers
3- Create the dataset that will be used

I believe that pandas has some commands that will help you, just find the patterns to define what are "questions" and "answers" in this dataset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).